# sequential compactness implies compactness (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> I came across a proof for "$M$ is sequentially compact" $\Longrightarrow$ "$M$ is compact". Other proofs I've come across are really long and complicated, in comparison, this proof is really short and elementary.. it feels too good to be true. I guess my question is, are there any mistakes (or even slight inaccuracies) with the proof? and if not, why is it not more well known?

$\textit{Lemma.}$ If $M$ is sequentially compact and $\{U_\alpha \ \vert \ \alpha\in I\}$ is an open cover of $M$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for each $x\in M$, $B(x;\epsilon)\subseteq U_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in I$.

$\textit{Proof.}$ We prove by contradiction, assume that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $x\in M$ such that for each $\alpha\in I$, $B(x;\epsilon)\not\subseteq U_\alpha$. Now choose $x_n$ so that $B(x_n;1/n)\not\subseteq U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in I$. Then $(x_n)$ is a sequence from $M$ (which is sequentially compact), so there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converges to some point $p\in M$ as $k\to \infty$.

There must be some $\alpha_0\in I$ for which $p\in U_{\alpha_0}$ and hence, there also exists an $r_0>0$ for which $B(p;r_0)\subseteq U_{\alpha_0}$. Now choose $N\in \{n_k \ \vert \ k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ large enough so that $d(p,x_N)<r_0/2$ and $1/N<r_0/2$. So if $y\in B(x_N,1/N)$, then
\begin{align*}
d(p,y)\leq d(p,x_N)+d(x_N,y)<r_0,
\end{align*}
which means that $y\in B(p;r_0)$. Therefore, $B(x_N;1/N)\subseteq B(p;r_0)\subseteq U_{\alpha_0}$, which is a contradiction.

$\textit{Theorem.}$ If a metric space $M$ is sequentially compact, then $M$ is compact.

$\textit{Proof.}$ Let $\{U_\alpha \ \vert \ \alpha\in I\}$ be an open cover of $M$, then by the lemma, there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for each $x\in M$, $B(x;\epsilon)\subseteq U_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in I$. Additionally, $M$ is totally bounded (assuming pre-existing knowledge that "$M$ is sequentially compact" $\Longrightarrow$ "$M$ is totally bounded"), that is, $M\subseteq B(y_1;\epsilon)\cup B(y_2;\epsilon)\cup \cdots \cup B(y_k;\epsilon)$ for some points $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_k\in M$. However, for each $1\leq i\leq k$, $B(y_i;\epsilon)\subseteq U_{\alpha_i}$ for some $\alpha_i\in I$. Thus, $\{U_{\alpha_1},U_{\alpha_2},\ldots,U_{\alpha_k}\}$ is a finite subcover of $\{U_\alpha\}$ that covers $M$.

Comment: This seems correct. In fact, it is almost exactly the proof given in Munkres' Topology.

Comment: You need to make it clear from the start that you’re talking about **metric** spaces: the statement in the title is false in general.